# How to work with 'Add items to cart' dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Can someone help me how to update a List in "cart_products.dart" on clicking "addToCart" button from a different dart file(different UI)? Hard coded List is working but I have no idea how to update the List dynamically. It would be a great help for new comers if someone can demonstrate with a simple example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global list items

**In your main.dart file**

```
ValueNotifier itemsNotifier = ValueNotifier([]);

void main() {
 // ...
}
```

**Anywhere (different dart file)**

```
List _tmpList = itemsNotifier.value;
_tmpList.add(YOUR_ITEM);
itemsNotifier.value = _tmpList;
```

**Display list items like this**

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: itemsNotifier,
  builder: (context, items, _) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text("Item ${index}"),
        );
      }
    );
  }
),
```

Comment: It worked!. But i wanted to know any side effects of using global variables. It is because if I declare everything as a global variable, how it will impact my application in terms of performance and maintenance. Also can you compare your solution with above one given by Jay dangar. Also suggest me on how to remove/update an item. Thank you.

Comment: If it works as you said, mark the answer as the correct one to help future readers

Comment: Lol. `ValueNotifier` update it's value using separated thread, as you build a separated StatefulWidget and call setState on it. When you use `setState` in your widget, the whole page is rebuilt which may impact your app performance. Global variables, when used in a proper way are efficient and make your app run smoothly

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have an existing list like following,

final listItems = [item1,item2, item3];

if you want to add item4 in it, you need to call setState and inside that add logic, like following:

```
addItemInList(){
 setState{
   (){
     listItems.add(item4);
   }
 }
}
```

same applies for deletion and updation.